# Migrate gulp process to include typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, tsc, typescript2.0

I am updating the build process for an Angular 1.5.8 application, to allow development on Typescript.

After an over-complicated experience with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), the current build process is simple and only uses [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to build two bundles: `my-lib.js` and `my-app.js`. This way, the library, which is bigger, but more stable than my application code, doesn't have to compile so often and the compilation of the application-domain code only takes 0.1 sec. I am happy with that -- as well as the other developers.

Now we are looking forward to migrate to Angular 2.0 and want to start development in [Typescript](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes), but I'm not sure on how to integrate it on the build process and even the best approach on how to do it: should it be preferred to use `tsc` only to compile Typescript into Javascript and let Browserify handle the dependencies? Or should I use `tsc` as my main build tool and let it resolve dependencies, create mapping files and make the bundles?

Both Typescript and Gulp are evolving very fast and I cannot find documentation for this use on their documentations ([1](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes), [2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html)). I would appreciate feedback from experienced people also working on the latest versions of these technologies.

Comment: we have gone thru exact same process at my organization, we have taken approach of using tsc as transpiler. and mostly used gulp for everything else, so its a minimal impact to current upgrade.

Comment: thank you, @entre, how did you manage the dependencies from JS to TS and vice-versa?

Comment: from `ts2js` nothing to be done, as ts is converted to js and all dependencies are managed angular's string based di, so as such no change for you. for `js2ts` you will need to define interfaces, so start with the most core part i.e. module with least dependencies. so less interface definitions are needed

Comment: thank you again, @entre, and what's your approach to the usage of `tsc`? do you run it before `gulp` process starts? or use `tsfy`? or use `gulp-typescipt`? I like the way `browserify` works, because it feels close to the standard compilation tools, but to configure it up to the point `gulp` is a mere starter feels to me too much like `grunt`.

Comment: we are using webpack, read that it easier than browsify. I do feel the same that they are similar to grunt and i love gulp approach much more, but then angular2 is using webpack, so we moved tsc to webpack loader, so very less work left for gulp. [must read](https://www.toptal.com/front-end/webpack-browserify-gulp-which-is-better)

Comment: thank you again, @entre, could you please share your build process, or your build process guidelines,if you'd be more comfortable with?

Comment: its very similar to the link provided in the earlier comments, the ts 2 js + html bunding + css bunding + minification + tslint is all done by webpack. gulp is used to start the server (we will mostly move this to webpack-dev-server very soon), and to run tests, plus other git/publish tasks (kind of Continuious Deployment) process

Comment: just to add one more thing, gulp is there still for bower bundling + wiredep stuff

Comment: @MaxwellLasky, thank you for your opinion, but I had already an over-complicated process based on Grunt and I wouldn't like to repeat the same error again. If you're kind to provide more information I can consider your approach, though.

Comment: @entre, `tsc` can provide `ts` and `js` bundling; it can also watch for changes and the same applies to `sass`  compiler. So, what's the advantage of having `Gulp` at all?

Answer (score 6):

Moving comments to answer:

We have doing very similar exercise at my organization, towards the end of it.
We have used webpack for most of the stuff, though webpack feels little grunt'y and after gulp, I am not a big fan of grunt.

We have used webpack to convert ts to js, bunding, minification. We have not used it yet for html to js string or css in js.

regarding the di part, you will have to worry about only `js to ts`. `ts to js` is not an issue as it is taken care by angular's string based di. regarding `ts to ts`, you will need to defined needed interfaces. Those will help you in moving those `js to ts` in future. Better to start with core components with least dependencies.

**EDIT**
Just to answer the part regarding the advantages of having gulp: specifically in the migration scenarios is, the upgrade is not going to happen in one go, so whatever is moved to TS should be handled by tsc and remaining by gulp.

Also gulp is much larger than just ts to js, we are still using it to create deployment package, inject js into html, fixing boostrap font paths, converting small images to base64, etc etc....

Answer (score 3):

**tsc** has one purpose: to transpile (compile) typescript files.

**gulp**, on the other hand, is a build tool, which means it can run various tasks including compiling typescript, sass, minification, concatenation etc.

You can look here for an example on how to incorporate typescript and browserify using gulp: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html

Another approach, is not to use gulp at all, but rather use npm scripts, you can see a sample here: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/why-i-left-gulp-and-grunt-for-npm-scripts-3d6853dd22b8#.a7lwcmpaf

Comment: Actually, `tsc`, besides compiling TS into JS, can also compile legacy JS files, resolve dependencies and output a single JS bundle; please see the option `--outFile` here (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: You are right, but i just wanted to make sure the difference is clear. tsc, for example' can't compile sass files.

Comment: Thank you, @fatman, I am aware that I still need Gulp tasks to handle `sass`, `html templates`, etc ... my doubt, though, is regarding whether to integrate `tsc` as a first step in my `javascript process` or to replace this task with a `typescript process` to handle all application code.

Comment: You can let tsc do all the minification/concatenation and then you don't need a js task, or you can just let it transpile the code to js and let gulp do the rest.

Comment: That was my idea @fatman, the problem is that, as long as I know, using the `--outFile` option requires `--module amd` or `--module system` and I would rather stick with `--module commonjs` whose loader is integrated in node.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the absolute simplest way to do this is to use [Zwitterion](https://github.com/lastmjs/zwitterion). You can read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/zwitterion-transpilation-made-simple-a9baa407b006) for a quick introduction.

Zwitterion allows you to include TypeScript directly into the browser through normal script tags. All features of TypeScript are automatically available, because the code is transpiled server-side on a file-by-file basis as it is served to the client. Under the hood, it uses SystemJS to emulate the real ES module loader behavior that will be standard in all browsers. If you need this to work in production, you can create a static build with Zwitterion. All of this eschews bundling, so you'll have to decide on what your needs are for performance. Personally, I'm betting on performance not being that big of an issue with HTTP2, and I prefer the simplest of builds to the complication that webpack and all of its friends bring.

Answer (score 0):

As you are moving forward with typescript, my recommendation would be to integrate any module bundler such as webpack (my favorite) Internally it will use ts loader to transpile the code. Also along with compile, you would be able to use ts lint for static code analysis (webpack would take care of it). Webpack also helps if you want to have multiple modules created. Try out yomen https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp . Once scaffolded you can refer to generated gulp files. It would give you an idea about typescript integration.

Comment: Hi, @Manish, as I said, I already have a process using Gulp and I don't want to migrate to Webpack. I also had many-many problems with Yeoman, so I won't try it neither.

Answer (score 0):

```
The best way to do this without overengineering your gulp setup is to use the plain typescript compiler:

1. Install typescript locally(it won't conflict with your global tsc):
    npm i typescript --save-dev

2. Add tsc as npm script(inside package.json).
    "scripts": {
        "tsc": "tsc"
    }

3. Create proper tsconfig.json for your needs and put it in the same folder as package.json
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

4. Use tsc compiler directly from gulp
    var child_process = require("child_process");

    gulp.task("build", function(cb) {
        var tsc = child_process.spawn("npm", ["-s", "run", "tsc"], {stdio: "inherit", cwd: __dirname});
        tsc.on("close", function(code) {
            console.log("Tsc finished with code", code);
            cb();
        });
    });
```

Tip. Use [https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence](http://gulp-sequence) and vote up :)